# JSON GET Method request

Tags: json, iphone

I have developed a iphone application that need to send User name and Password through HTTP authentication request header. can any one guide me or sent the source code for that functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement the NSURLConnection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: method.

```
- (void)request:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge { 
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) { 
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential
                                              credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                              password:@"password" 
                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone]; 
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential 
               forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge]; 
    } 
    else { 
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } 
}
```

Edit: Or you could simply send the credentials in the URL in the format http://username:password@www.example.com/